# Integration : linear and exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

I just cannot see how to begin with this sum

this was asked in my exam recently.

can someone help in a way to work with sums similar to this type?

[image]

Comment: ok sorry let me edit i thought its to solved by that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so based on the new question, using the same idea as my previous answer (the product rule in reverse), noting that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left (x e^{x + \frac{1}{x}} \right ) = \left (1 + x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) e^{x + \frac{1}{x}},$$
one has
$$\int \left (1 +x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) e^{x + \frac{1}{x}} \, dx = \int \frac{d}{dx} \left (x e^{x + \frac{1}{x}} \right ) \, dx = x e^{x + \frac{1}{x}} + C.$$

Comment: but my question is that isn't it much intuitive to consider that function, the question becomes easy in an exam with multiple choices (or rather for a person with appreciable analytical skills) one (beginners like me) may get stomped.

Comment: I agree, being expected to spot such a thing can be difficultly, particularly if you have never seen such a thing before and under examination conditions! In general, the method being applied here is known as the "reverse product rule". It states that if $f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions, then $$\int [f(x) \cdot g'(x) + f'(x) \cdot g(x)] \, dx = f(x) \cdot g(x) + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\frac{d}{dx} (e^x f(x)) = e^x [f(x) + f'(x)],$$
giving
$$\int e^x [f(x) + f'(x)] \, dx = \int \frac{d}{dx} [e^x f(x)] \, dx = e^x f(x) + C.$$

Comment: yes I indeed know that but in some sums like this one rearrangement seems difficult, my initial thought was that we must do the  sum in the picture by this method.